# Call function with variable number of arguments

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I've a function

```
int send_email(const char * to, const char * subject, const char * body, size_t nbr_attachments, ...);
```

it all works fine. I can use it for sending an email with no attachments:
send_email("test@example.com", "TEST", "TESTBODY", 0, NULL);

Or with one attachment:

```
send_email("test@example.com", "TEST", "TESTBODY", 1, "/tmp/attachment1.pdf");
```

Or with two attachments:

```
send_email("test@example.com", "TEST", "TESTBODY", 2, "/tmp/attachment1.pdf", "/tmp/attachment2.pdf");
```

However, let's say I've a linked list of attachments

```
typedef struct attachments attachments;
typedef struct attachments {
    const char * attachment;
    next * attachments
};
```

How can I call send_email with the attachments from that list? That is

```
int nbr_attachments = 0;
attachments * itr = att;
while (itr) {
    nbr_attachments++;
    itr = itr->next;
}


send_email("test@example.com", "TEST", "TESTBODY", nbr_attachments, ??????);
```

Comment: Change the `send_email` function to take the linked list instead of `...`.

Comment: Maybe [C FAQ handoff](https://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html) to compile a `vsend_email`.

Comment: You can steer a LOT of potentially misguided assumptions about your question if you clarify one thing in your post: You said, "I've a function". Please elaborate more. Is `send_mail` a function of **your** doing, that **you** authored or can otherwise change at-will? It makes a world of difference (literally the difference of "just do this" vs. "can't be done").

Comment: Presumably, you meant to ask how to call the function with a linked list off attachments without changing the function definition, right? One long hand way to address this if you know the maximum number of nodes in the linked list would be to create a separate function with a pointer to the linked list as an argument. Then, that function can count the number of nodes and call the send_email function with the appropriate number of hard-coded arguments.

Comment: C variadic functions allow you to *hard code* a sequence of variable arguments.  They do not provide a means to construct the variable arguments dynamically at run time.  It sounds like the latter is what you're after, and if so, then you need either a separate function for that or some kind of special handling in the implementation of the current function.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function some sort of reference to the list of attachments in a fixed number of arguments. That can be various things, including:

- A pointer to the start of a linked list of attachments (one argument).
- An array of pointers to the names of the attachments and the number of names (two arguments).
- A pointer to a function that is passed an index *i* and returns either a pointer to information about attachment number *i* (if there is one) or a null pointer (if there is no such attachment) (one argument).